# How to handle the time complexity for an optimization that depends on numerical values

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis

I'm working on an algorithm and there is an optimization I applied that is unpredictable because it depends on calculations done on top of the input trough several iterations, so as the input values change, the optimization gain oscillates (between a 20% to 90% step count reduction) as is adaptive to the input.

Is there any formal approach to handle these situations in respect to time analysis?

Comment: You do it the same way as always: You either take a worst-case input or you do an average case analysis for a suitably chosen distribution on your inputs.

Comment: Agreed; this is nothing special, but business as usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach not mentioned above is [parametrized complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity). The idea is to express the complexity of the algorithm with respect to a parameter of the input. A classical example is when the input is a graph and the parameter is the tree-width. But more generally, the parameter will be something that is typically not easily computable from the input. On a related note, the [condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) can be seen as a particular case of parametrized complexity when dealing with numerical problems.